# Matplotlib - rotating text on log scale where angles are incorrectly rounded

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, logarithm

I am trying to have text rotate onto a plot which is shown on log scale. When I compute the angles (based on the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111258/5134817)) **the angles are getting incorrectly rounded to 0 or 90 degrees**. This is because the angles are computed on a linear scale first, and then transformed. This calculation in linear space is the cause of the trouble. Even in a situation where I know the gradient, (either in a linear or logarithmic scale), I am not sure how I can put this onto the graph correctly.

## MWE

[image]

```
import matplotlib as mpl

rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preview': True,
    "font.size": 50,
    'mathtext.default': 'regular',
    'axes.titlesize': 55,
    "axes.labelsize": 55,
    "legend.fontsize": 50,
    "xtick.labelsize": 50,
    "ytick.labelsize": 50,
    'figure.titlesize': 55,
    'figure.figsize': (10, 6.5),  # 15, 9.3
    'text.latex.preamble': [
        r"""\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,mathtools,nicefrac,letltxmacro,fixcmex}
        """],
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": "computer modern roman",
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, InsetPosition, mark_inset
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.exp(x**2)
g = 2*x*y  # Gradient.
lg = 2 * x  # Gradient on a log scale.

plt.clf()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yscale('log')
for x in [0,2,4,7,18]:
    angle_data = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(2 * x * np.exp(x**2), 1))
    y = np.exp(x**2)
    angle_screen = plt.gca().transData.transform_angles(np.array((angle_data,)), np.array([x, y]).reshape((1, 2)))[0]
    plt.gca().text(x, y, r'A', rotation_mode='anchor', rotation=angle_screen, horizontalalignment='center')
plt.ylim(1e0, 1e180)
plt.xlim(-1, 20)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.title(r'$\exp(x^2)$', y=1.05)
plt.savefig('logscale.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

### A few ideas?

I had tried to use the fact that for very large functions I can calculate the difference from 90 degrees using arctan(x) ~ pi/2 - arctan(1/x), and the former angle uses the low angle approximation so is just 1/x. However, after plugging this into `transform_angles` this is rounded incorrectly.

## A slight hack of a solution

If I guess the aspect ratio of the figure (c0.6) and then also adjust for the difference in scales (x in `[0:20]` while log10(y) is in `[0:180]`, giving a difference of 9 in scale), then I can get the following, although I don't think this is particularly sustainable, especially if I want to tweak something later.

[image]

```
# The 9 comes from tha fact that x is in [0:20], log10(y) is in [0, 180]. The factor of 0.6 is roughly the aspect ratio of the main plot shape.
plt.gca().text(x, y, r'A', rotation_mode='anchor', rotation=np.rad2deg(np.arctan(0.6 * x/9.0)), horizontalalignment='center')
```

Comment: The problem is that the angle in data coordinates is essentially 90 degrees for those Texts in question.

Comment: Correct, and frustratingly I know what the gradient should be on the log scale.

Comment: I suppose using angles via `arctan` is not possible here. I didn't look into the otjher answers to the linked question too deeply; maybe they are better suited for your case?

Answer (score 2):

I updated the [solution to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111799/4124317) with a class `RotationAwareAnnotation2`, which will be better suited here. It would first transform the points into screen coordinates, and then apply the rotation.

This this case it would look as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as mtext
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms


class RotationAwareAnnotation2(mtext.Annotation):
    def __init__(self, s, xy, p, pa=None, ax=None, **kwargs):
        self.ax = ax or plt.gca()
        self.p = p
        if not pa:
            self.pa = xy
        kwargs.update(rotation_mode=kwargs.get("rotation_mode", "anchor"))
        mtext.Annotation.__init__(self, s, xy, **kwargs)
        self.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())
        if 'clip_on' in kwargs:
            self.set_clip_path(self.ax.patch)
        self.ax._add_text(self)

    def calc_angle(self):
        p = self.ax.transData.transform_point(self.p)
        pa = self.ax.transData.transform_point(self.pa)
        ang = np.arctan2(p[1]-pa[1], p[0]-pa[0])
        return np.rad2deg(ang)

    def _get_rotation(self):
        return self.calc_angle()

    def _set_rotation(self, rotation):
        pass

    _rotation = property(_get_rotation, _set_rotation)


x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
f = lambda x: np.exp(x**2)
y = f(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set(yscale = 'log', ylim=(1e0, 1e180), xlim=(-1, 20), xlabel=r'$x$')

annots= []
for xi in [0,2,4,7,18]:
    an = RotationAwareAnnotation2("A", xy=(xi,f(xi)), p=(xi+.01,f(xi+.01)), ax=ax,
                                  xytext=(-1,1), textcoords="offset points", 
                                  ha="center", va="baseline", fontsize=40)
    annots.append(an)

ax.set_title(r'$\exp(x^2)$', y=1.05)
fig.savefig('logscale.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works a treat, although I am unsure what a few of the parameters are, I've been able to figure out `p` from the example, but could you perhaps add a few lines of docstring to explain some of the others? (e.g. `pa`, although I assume `xytext` and `textcoords` can be looked up).

Comment: I think I explained it in [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111799/4124317).